# Recursively getting a root ID of tree in Postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a Postgres table users (E_8_User) which contains User_id as a primary key, Boss as a foreign key to the same table (it is not nullable, if some user doesn't have boss, its Boss attribute = user_id).
I need to get their bosses for all users in the table, so I'm trying to write CTE query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE herarchy_reports AS (
    SELECT E_8_User.User_id, E_8_User.Boss, 1 as lvl, E_8_User.User_id as RootUserID
    FROM E_8_User
    WHERE E_8_User.User_id=E_8_User.Boss
    UNION ALL
    SELECT usr.User_id, usr.Boss, lvl+1 as lvl, rep.RootUserID
    FROM herarchy_reports as rep JOIN E_8_User as usr ON
    rep.user_id=usr.Boss
)
SELECT * FROM herarchy_reports ORDER BY RootUserID;
```

But it doesn't work: DB is constantly performing query.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a typical recusive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select u.user_id, u.boss, 1 as lvl from e_8_user u
    union all
    select u.user_id, c.boss, lvl + 1
    from cte c 
    inner join e_8_user u on u.boss = c.user_id and u.user_id != c.user_id
)
select user_id, boss 
from cte c
where lvl = (select max(c1.lvl) from cte c1 where c1.user_id = c.user_id) 
order by user_id
```

In the recursive query, the trick is to stop recursing when a record is joined with itself (`u.boss = c.user_id and u.user_id != c.user_id`).

Then, in the outer query, you want to select the record that has the greatest level for each user.

Assuming the following sample data:

```
user_id | boss
------: | ---:
      1 |    1
      2 |    1
      3 |    2
      4 |    3
      5 |    2
      6 |    6
      7 |    6
```

The query produces:

```
user_id | boss
------: | ---:
      1 |    1
      2 |    1
      3 |    1
      4 |    1
      5 |    1
      6 |    6
      7 |    6
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bfbbf9dd48c65cd0fe071cc685692650)**

In Postgres, we can simplify the outer query with `distinct on`:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select u.user_id, u.boss, 1 as lvl from e_8_user u
    union all
    select u.user_id, c.boss, lvl + 1
    from cte c 
    inner join e_8_user u on u.boss = c.user_id and u.user_id != c.user_id
)
select distinct on (user_id) user_id, boss 
from cte c
order by user_id, lvl desc
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BSQaWRlq)**

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!